# Read from two tables information

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

How can i convert this code to read information from the two tables.

```
Private Sub GenerateDynamicUserControl()
    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear()
    Dim dt As DataTable = New ClassBLL().GetItems()

    If dt IsNot Nothing Then

        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim listItems As ListItem() = New ListItem(dt.Rows.Count - 1) {}

            For i As Integer = 0 To 1 - 1

                For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                    Dim listItem As New ListItem()
                    listItems(i) = listItem
                    'Dim ms As New MemoryStream(CType(row("userPic"), Byte()))
                    listItems(i).Width = FlowLayoutPanel1.Width - 30
                    listItems(i).Icon = orderPicFromString
                    listItems(i).Icon2 = orderPicFromString2
                    listItems(i).OrderFrom = row("orderfrom").ToString()
                    listItems(i).OrderTitle = orderTitleString
                    listItems(i).OrderReceiver = row("orderreceiver").ToString()
                    listItems(i).OrderTitle2 = orderTitleString2
                    'listItems(i).ButtonBackground = orderButtonBackString
                    listItems(i).ButtonText = row("orderstatus").ToString()
                    listItems(i).OrderDate = row("orderdate")
                    listItems(i).IDOrder = row("orderid").ToString()

                    If listItems(i).ButtonText = "Accepted" Then
                        listItems(i).ButtonBackground = Color.FromArgb(26, 168, 92)
                    ElseIf listItems(i).ButtonText = "Declined" Then
                        listItems(i).ButtonBackground = Color.FromArgb(246, 50, 90)
                    ElseIf listItems(i).ButtonText = "Proceed" Then
                        listItems(i).ButtonBackground = Color.FromArgb(255, 174, 33)
                    ElseIf listItems(i).ButtonText = "Waiting" Then
                        listItems(i).ButtonBackground = Color.FromArgb(53, 121, 255)
                    Else
                        listItems(i).ButtonBackground = Color.FromArgb(91, 146, 255)
                    End If
                    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(listItems(i))
                Next
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

So let me start with information about this that is in RED , i need to get this information from another table that is called "Profiles"

listItems(i).Icon = orderPicFromString

listItems(i).Icon2 = orderPicFromString2

listItems(i).OrderTitle = orderTitleString

listItems(i).OrderTitle2 = orderTitleString2

So this fields i need to read them from table "Profiles"

So next is as you see the code up calls Class GetItems:

```
Public Function GetItems() As DataTable
    Try
        Dim objdal As New ClassDAL()
        Return objdal.ReadItemsTable()
    Catch e As Exception
        Dim result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString())
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function

Public Function ReadItemsTable() As DataTable
    Using cons As New OleDbConnection(ServerStatus)
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand()
            cmd.Connection = cons
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM OrdersAssigned ORDER BY ID ASC"
            cons.Open()
            Using sda As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                Dim dt As New DataTable()
                sda.Fill(dt)
                Return dt
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

So this is main function to display the results from row("name")
Then i try to create like this:

```
'Declare Strings for OrderDisplay
Public orderFromString As String
Public orderTitleString As String
Public orderReceiveString As String
Public orderTitleString2 As String
Public orderButtonBackString As Color
Public orderButtonTextString As String
Public orderDateString As Date
Public orderIDString As String
Public orderPicFromString As Image
Public orderPicFromString2 As Image
'Get Accounts Name
Public orderAccountFrom As String
Public orderAccountTo As String

Public Sub GetUserPictureFrom()
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(ServerStatus)
        conn.Open()
        Dim sql As String = "Select userPicture From Profiles where userAccount=@GetLogin"
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GetLogin", orderAccountFrom)
            Dim imageData As Byte() = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())
            If imageData IsNot Nothing Then
                Using stream As New MemoryStream(imageData)
                    Dim backgroundImage As Image = Image.FromStream(stream)
                    orderPicFromString = backgroundImage
                End Using
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
Public Sub GetUserPictureTo()
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(ServerStatus)
        conn.Open()
        Dim sql As String = "Select userPicture From Profiles where userAccount=@GetLogin"
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GetLogin", orderAccountTo)
            Dim imageData As Byte() = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())
            If imageData IsNot Nothing Then
                Using stream As New MemoryStream(imageData)
                    Dim backgroundImage As Image = Image.FromStream(stream)
                    orderPicFromString2 = backgroundImage
                End Using
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Public Sub GetOrdersDisplay()
    Using cons As New OleDbConnection(ServerStatus)
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand()
            cmd.Connection = cons
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM OrdersAssigned ORDER BY ID ASC"
            cons.Open()
            Using rdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While rdr.Read()
                    orderAccountFrom = rdr("orderacc").ToString
                    orderAccountTo = rdr("orderreceiveracc").ToString
                End While
            End Using
            cmd.CommandText = "Select userPosition From Profiles where userAccount = @GetUser"
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GetUser", orderAccountFrom)
            Using rds As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While rds.Read()
                    orderTitleString = rds("userPosition").ToString
                End While
            End Using
            cmd.CommandText = "Select userPosition From Profiles where userAccount = @ToUser"
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ToUser", orderAccountTo).ToString()
            Using rdx As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While rdx.Read()
                    orderTitleString2 = rdx("userPosition").ToString
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    GetUserPictureFrom()
    GetUserPictureTo()
End Sub
```

What it needs to do is:

orderAccountFrom = rdr("orderacc").ToString

orderAccountTo = rdr("orderreceiveracc").ToString

will get the accounts from table OrdersAssigned  and search with them in table Profiles to get results userPosition
What means this

userx in Profiles has userPosition = Boss
usery in Profiles has userPosition = Worker
i want to fetch this information.
The same goes for the pictures each user has his own picture.

How can i manage to fix this issue so to get correct data?
How can i combine all of this inside the function ReadItemsTable() it would be better to be in one place everything so

listItems(i).Icon = orderPicFromString

listItems(i).Icon2 = orderPicFromString2

listItems(i).OrderTitle = orderTitleString

listItems(i).OrderTitle2 = orderTitleString2

to work correct to get information

Comment: I'm a little cloudy on the issue, perhaps you could show use your DB schema so we can better understand the structure of your database.  That aside, perhaps you could look at using a select query with a join condition to retrieve the required info from both tables in one pass

Comment: https://mega.nz/file/qQ9mUAaa#YoxQksBgj96ZCYf0sRqiwDF4uuqdHVNrha-objoymj4

Comment: Ok, well, you could use something like this _SELECT OrdersAssigned.orderacc, OrdersAssigned.orderfrom, Profiles.userName, Profiles.userPosition
FROM OrdersAssigned INNER JOIN Profiles ON OrdersAssigned.orderfrom = Profiles.userName_ as the base of your query. But honestly you've got some very real fundimental issues in your DB structure that should really be addressed.  Can not stress this enough, proper DB design and implementation makes everything above it easier

Comment: i do not sow logic in the above query that you present, how can it help to fetch userPosition and userPicture from table Profiles and use it in function to be called by row("name") ?

Comment: only this 2 things i need to fetch from the other table everything else is displayed by row("name") in function just need inside the (i). to get username -> go to Profiles get his results return back

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT OrdersAssigned.*,
              ProfilesFrom.userPosition AS UserPositionFrom,
              ProfilesFrom.userPicture AS UserPictureFrom,
              ProfilesTo.userPosition AS UserPositionTo,
              ProfilesTo.userPicture AS UserPictureTo
            FROM
              (OrdersAssigned
              LEFT OUTER JOIN Profiles AS ProfilesFrom ON OrdersAssigned.orderacc = ProfilesFrom.userAccount)
              LEFT OUTER JOIN Profiles AS ProfilesTo ON OrdersAssigned.orderreceiveracc = ProfilesTo.userAccount
            ORDER BY
              OrdersAssigned.ID ASC;"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: pretty much is clear to understand the thing i use to fix it is fix the query with JOIN and then in code just call the rows easy to understand :)